# "identifier not found" when trying to declare a list iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I am creating a Set class using the standard `list` container. When I declare the list iterator `iter`, I get an error:

> C3861 'iter':identifier not found

I have found a few examples of other people declaring list iterators in this way, but I may be misunderstanding something about iterators.

```
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Set
{
private:
    list<T> the_set;
    list<T>::iterator iter;
public:
    Set() {}
    virtual ~Set() {}

    void insert(const T& item) {
        bool item_found = false;
        for (iter = the_set.begin(); iter != the_set.end(); ++iter) {
            if (*iter == item) item_found = true;
        }
        if (!item_found) {
            iter = the_set.begin();
            while (item > *iter) {
                ++iter;
            }
            the_set.list::insert(iter, item);
        }
    }
}
```

The error is shown happening at the line:

```
list<T>::iterator iter;
```

Comment: Recommended reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Removing the 'using' statement and inserting std:: in the correct places may be a "better practice", but it doesn't change the performance of the code at all.

Comment: On a side note: you don't need `#include <iterator>` in this code, and `the_set.list::insert()` should be just `the_set.insert()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler gets confused by that line because it doesn't know what `list<T>` will be before actually specializing the class with some `T`.

More formally you would say that `list<T>::iterator` is a [*dependent name*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name).

The solution is to add a hint in form of the `typename` keyword to specify that the construct will refer to some type after all.

I.e. this should help:

```cpp
    typename list<T>::iterator iter;
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This fixed it :)

Comment: See [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)